# Crystal reports Showing Multiple pages of records using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report having a layout of payslip. The crystal report has a stored procedure as recordsource. the code is as follows.

```
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
             reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport2.rpt"));
             reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", @"BISWA-PC\SQLEXPRESS", "Forum_mall");
             reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@compId", compid);
             reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@DeptName", dept);
             reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@year_id", yearid);
             reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@month_id", monthid);
             CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```

The rows returned are 200 but the report is showing me the first record and a page link to go to the next page. When the link page is clicked it is giving this error message

Server Error in '/FORUM' Application.

The system cannot find the path specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The system cannot find the path specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

But asthonishly if I view the report in back end as Report viewer it is nicely formating the report as group wise employee id in all the 200 records.

The settings given in the report are IN details section 'Keep together is clicked on Group Footer section 'New page before' is clicked on (I tried the New page after also) Group Header section no selection has been made.

CAN ANYBODY HELP ME WHAT IS WRONG. I AM RUNNING THE PROGRAM IN WEB USING ASP.NET 3.5 AND CRYSTAL REPORTS.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: sounds like you are using this line incorrectly `reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport2.rpt"));` try something like the following 
`reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport2.rpt"));`

Answer (score 1):

you can find your solution from

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual)